# How can I implement a function i created that requires me to read in from a file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function:

```
    errorLim = 0.3
    def getQMulti(ppm,errorLim):
        x = (ppm-peakAvg)/errorLim
        q = getQ(x)
        x0=2.0
        q0=getQ(x0)
        QMulti = 1.0+(q/math.abs(q0))
        return QMulti
```

and this `QMulti` function uses another function called `getQ(x)` which is like this:

```
def getQ(x):
    q = math.log(1.0- erf(abs(x)/SQRT2))
    return q
```

I have a file called expAtoms and it looks like this:

```
3.H5 5.40077
3.H5 5.40001
5.H5 5.70502
4.H8 7.55438
5.H1' 5.43574
""
""
""
6.H6 7.96178
6.H5 5.71068
```

How can I implement this function? I currently have code which reads the first column of `expAtoms`, sees if any values repeat, and then if it does, takes the average and outputs it to a file.

In my function, I have `ppm-peakAvg`. My current code gives the average, and I want to compute this function for each atom in my `expAtoms` file.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys


exp = 'expAtoms.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(exp, sep = ' ', header = None)
df.columns = ["Atom","ppm"]
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

df2 =pd.read_csv(pred, sep = r'\s+', header = None)
df2.columns = ["Atoms","ppms","error"]

gb = (df.groupby("Atom", as_index=False).agg({"ppm":["count","mean"]}).rename(columns={"count":"nVa", "mean":"avgppm"}))

gb.head()

gb.columns = gb.columns.droplevel()
gb = gb.rename(columns={"":"Atom"})
gb.merge(df2, left_on='Atom', right_on='Atoms', how='left').drop(['Atoms','ppms'], axis=1)
gb.to_csv("output.txt", sep =" ", index=False)
```

I want my output to look like this, so how can I add a column that computes this `QMulti` function?:

```
      Atom nVa avgppm   QMulti   
  7.H2   2      7.853    0.000    
  9.H2   2      7.458    0.000    
 20.H2   1      7.898    0.000    
 21.H2   1      8.113    0.000   
 8.H1'   2      5.238    0.002   
22.H1'   2      5.523    0.002
```

Comment: What's the input to your function? What column?

Comment: the input is the second column in my `expAtoms` file

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the `ppm` is the second column in my `expAtoms` file and the `errorLim` is a variable I defined about with the value 0.3

Comment: Yes but do you want to apply this before your groupby or after?

Comment: I was thinking after because after the groupby is when I have the mean, but I don't know if that matters

Comment: If that's the case, the input will no longer be ppm, because after the groupby you have something else...

Comment: So how can I do it before the groupby? And in that case how can I use the average?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I just realized my function is using another function inside it, I updated my question to reflect this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153049/discussion-between-user8290579-and-cs).